# Как добавить данные в динамические столбцы DataGrid wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

долгое время не могу понять/справиться с тем, как добавлять данные в динамические столбцы. У меня динамически создаются столбцы(с этим проблем нет) и я даже могу приклеить им биндинги, но тут вопрос - как мне выводить данные, если они могут быть не одинаковые по кол-ву. Создавать для каждой колонки отдельный лист? если да то как? Или вот у меня мысль, просто в тупую выводить данные в определенные колонки через DataGrid.Item=..., но тогда я не понимаю как смещать колонку, потому как она привязана к первой. И вот как мне быть в такой ситуации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1 таблица == 1 класс. Если вы хотите пихнуть в одну таблицу несколько классов, то сделайте один класс, который будет содержать в себе свойства с типом других классов и привязывайте как `{Binding SecondClass.Property}`. Если у вас вообще не связанные друг с другом классы, то делайте разные таблицы, привязывая их к разным коллекциям.